# HowTo Serve JSP and servlets on Win7 Pro with dynamic redirect service

Tags: jsp, web-applications, iis-7, webserver, tomcat7

I am having an issue serving a tiny little Java Web app consisting of 3 jsp pages and no more then 3 servlets.  Please forgive my lack of knowledge, and I will give you all the information that I have (if I didnt list it, just ask).  I am running Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 as a service.  This is a Win 7 Pro x64 box.  I have a dynamic redirect service on No-Ip.com that will be direct traffic to port 8080 (can be changed to whatever I need).

I dont know where to start.  Can I use IIS7 or do I need Apache HTTP Server, which is easier... this is just a small site?  Will I need isapi_redirect.dll?  How do I configure it to serve my site?  Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.  I am rather frustrated about the level of knowledge needed to host your own small site.

Still not working...  maybe we can go over my local setup.  I will post all answers when solved.

Comment: Tomcat can serve the content directly, so unless it's doing something useful (like serving an asp type web app) the IIS can be stopped.  If the other stuff you need to serve is static, Tomcat can do that as well, no need for another server there either.

Comment: index.jsp has three textboxes, returns servlet that gets user info from mySql db and returns on next jsp...  that then has check boxes for each item from the users profile.  they check what they want and it calls another servlet which processes the request, sends an email, etc and returns the last confirmation jsp...  thats it.

Comment: if that's all just allow your Tomcat server to serve the pages directly (configure Windows Firewall to let Tomcat's traffic pass) and that's it, no extra programs needed.

Comment: There has to be more to it then that.... I feel a little lost, and thats not normal for me.  I have to be missing something

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I can't see your problem - Tomcat **is** a functional standalone website perfectly capable of doing what you describe - what exactly makes you think there should be more to it?

Comment: how do I tell my system that when someone types in this.site.com it pulls up my page.  I do not do this for a living so please excuse my lack of knowledge.  I can configure my router to redirect this.site.com to port 8080... is that about it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13569/discussion-between-fvu-and-dave-p)

Comment: I've typed the entire list of instructions in the SO chat linked above, please come to chat so we can solve any remaining questions you may have.

Comment: I now am able to go to the url but get my router logon page...  what is next

Comment: please follow the link to the chat page, we can continue this discussion there

Comment: I was wrong... router is Ultraline series3 9100em from verizon